# OnClick Solve equation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple html page that would have three input variables (A,B,C). Once the user has provided these values they will press "calculate", and the JavaScript will run the  values through the following equations

```
((A + B)/2) * 3 = X
```

and

```
(C * 2) = Y
```

The answers will appear as outputs of `X` Value and `Y` Value. 
Here is an image:

[image]

I have written the HTML but i'm having difficulty with the JavaScript. Could someone please help :) Thank you so much in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  
  
  
  
  
</head>

<body>

<body class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
    <h1 align="center">Example</h1>
<form class="form-horizontal well w3-center" style="max-width: 850px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
  
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">A</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text"  name="A" class="ratecalcfield"></input>
    </div>
</div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">B</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text"  name="B" class="ratecalcfield"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">C</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text"   name="C" class="ratecalcfield"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">X Value</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="x" class="ratecalcfield"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Y Value</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="y" class="ratecalcfield"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group w3-margin-top">
                        <div class="controls">
                        <input type="button" class="w3-button w3-blue w3-padding-large" style="max-width: 200px; width: 100%;" onclick="cmdCalc_Click()" value="Calculate" name="cmdCalc"></input>
                    </div>
                   
                </div>
            </form>
  
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
    function cmdCalc_Click() {
            calculate();
    }

    function calculate() {
        A = parseInt(document.getElementById("A").value);
        B = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value);
        C = parseInt(document.getElementById("C").value);
        
        x = document.getElementById("x");
        y = document.getElementById("y");
        
    x.innerHTML = (3 * C);
    y.innerHTML = (((A + B) / 2 ) * 2));
    }
```

Comment: What problems do you have? I cannot see any JS code. maybe this is the problem ...

Comment: I just added my attempt for the javascript, it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here.

I have appended to each input an unique `id`. After that I have got the elements in JavaScript via `document.getElementById`. Each element has a `value` property which holds the `value` of the `input element`. On the `click` event, I get the values of `A`, `B` and `C` and calculates them. After calculation I set the values to `X` and `Y`.

```js
var a = document.getElementById('A');
var b = document.getElementById('B');
var c = document.getElementById('C');
var x = document.getElementById('X');
var y = document.getElementById('Y');

function cmdCalc_Click(){
   x.value = ((Number.parseInt(a.value) + Number.parseInt(b.value)) / 2) * 3
   y.value = c.value * 2;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal well w3-center" style="max-width: 850px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
  
   <div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label">A</label>
     <div class="controls">
         <input id="A" type="text"  name="A" class="ratecalcfield">
     </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">B</label>
      <div class="controls">
         <input id="B" type="text"  name="B" class="ratecalcfield">
      </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="control-group">
       <label class="control-label">C</label>
       <div class="controls">
          <input id="C" type="text"   name="C" class="ratecalcfield">
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">X Value</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input id="X" type="text" name="x" class="ratecalcfield">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="control-group">
         <label class="control-label">Y Value</label>
         <div class="controls">
             <input id="Y" type="text" name="y" class="ratecalcfield">
         </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="control-group w3-margin-top">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="button" class="w3-button w3-blue w3-padding-large" style="max-width: 200px; width: 100%;" onclick="cmdCalc_Click()" value="Calculate" name="cmdCalc">
         </div>                 
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

all html error corrected.

forces inputs to be number (avoid unnecessary parseInt in js).

set a class to work with.

make the calculation.

set new x and y values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span6">
                    <form class="form-horizontal well w3-center" style="max-width: 850px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">A</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="number" id="A" class="ratecalcfield">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">B</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="number"  id="B" class="ratecalcfield">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">C</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="number" id="C" class="ratecalcfield">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">X Value</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="number"  id="x" class="ratecalcfield">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Y Value</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="number"  id="y" class="ratecalcfield">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group w3-margin-top">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="button" class="w3-button w3-blue w3-padding-large" style="max-width: 200px; width: 100%;" onclick="cmdCalc_Click()" value="Calculate" name="cmdCalc">
                            </div>               
                    </form> 
                </div> 
            </div>   
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        function cmdCalc_Click() {
            let x = document.getElementById("x");
            let y = document.getElementById("y");
            const Preset = new whatToDo(x, y);
            const result = Preset.calculate();
            x.value = result.x;
            y.value = result.y;
        }
        class whatToDo {
            constructor(x, y) {
                this.A = (document.getElementById("A").value);
                this.B = (document.getElementById("B").value);
                this.C = (document.getElementById("C").value);
            }
            calculate() {
                return {
                    x: (3 * this.C),
                    y: (((this.A + this.B) / 2) * 2)
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary use "id" in the variable fields, just get them through the field name using getElementsByName ('inputNameHere')[0].value)

```js
function cmdCalc_Click(){
        var a = Number.parseInt(document.getElementsByName('A')[0].value);
        var b = Number.parseInt(document.getElementsByName('B')[0].value);
        var c = Number.parseInt(document.getElementsByName('C')[0].value);
        var x = Number.parseInt(document.getElementsByName('X')[0].value);
        var y = Number.parseInt(document.getElementsByName('Y')[0].value);

    e1 = ((a + b)/2) * 3
    if(e1 == x && x != 0){
        alert("Correct " + e1 + " is equal to " + x);
    }

    e2 = (c * 2)
    if(e2 == y && y != 0){
        alert("Correct" + e2 + " is equal to " + y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript `eval` function to calculate any expression.

```js
function cmdCalc_Click() {
    var a = document.querySelector('[name=A]').value;
    var b = document.querySelector('[name=B]').value;
    var c = document.querySelector('[name=C]').value;
    var x = document.querySelector('[name=x]');
    var y = document.querySelector('[name=y]');

    x.value = eval("((" + a + " + " + b + ")/2) * 3");
    y.value = eval("(" + c + " * 2)");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>

    <body class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                <h1 align="center">Example</h1>
                <form class="form-horizontal well w3-center" style="max-width: 850px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">A</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="A" class="ratecalcfield">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">B</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="B" class="ratecalcfield">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">C</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="C" class="ratecalcfield">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">X Value</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="x" class="ratecalcfield">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Y Value</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="y" class="ratecalcfield">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group w3-margin-top">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="button" class="w3-button w3-blue w3-padding-large" style="max-width: 200px; width: 100%;" onclick="cmdCalc_Click()" value="Calculate" name="cmdCalc">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you didnt add the A, B, C, X, and Y Ids to each form fields and you are using innerHTML to set form value for X and Y.
X & Y is a text field and you should set the values as

```
 X.value=(3*C);
 Y.value=((A+B)/2);

Set the ids that you are referencing in javascript to the appropraite text fields like:

<input type="text" id="A" name="A" class="">
```

etc.

now the document.getElementById("A"); can find the field with id A and get its value.

`Another problem:`

Using value to set the value of an textfield not innerHTML

Also modify your onclick event with the below code so you wont have the for submitted and the page loaded.

```
 onclick="cmdCal_Click(); return false"
```